# creating a data generator/recycler for influxdb

Tags: python, database, bash, influxdb, kapacitor

i want to create some sort of a data generator for a lab environment.

i thought of creating some kind of a script, that will get db name and comma separated metric names, and will fetch old data from the influx-db, change its time stamp to the current time, and save it back to influx-db.

i'm not sure what would be the best and easiest way to do it,
python script? kapacitor udf ?
any ideas ?

i'm new to the tick environment so i can really use some ideas :)

thanks,
David,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the perfect way, 
quick and easy, using kapacitor, not even need to create a udf...

create this tick script and define it as a kapacitor task:

```
var data = batch
    |query(''' SELECT * FROM "My_DB"."My_RP"."My_Measurement" ''')
        .period(1d)
        .every(30s)
        .offset(10d)
data
    |shift(10d)
    |influxDBOut()
        .create()
        .database('My_DB')
        .measurement('My_Measurement')
```

works like magic !